# How can I link two html forms with one google sheet?

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
         const scriptURL = ''
         const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

         form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
           e.preventDefault()
           fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
             .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
             .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
         })
       </script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="background-form">
       <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
         <input placeholder="Your name" name="Name" type="text" tabindex="1" required >
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <input placeholder="Your Email Address" name="Email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="Phone_No" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <select name="Category_Interested" title="Center" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="">&nbsp;Category Interested In</option>
          <option value="Modular Furnitur">Modular Furniture</option>
          <option value="Home Furnishing">Home Furnishing</option>
          <option value="Kitchen Appliances">Kitchen Appliances</option>
         </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="callus">
         <a href="tel: +91 9711600069"><span class="call-span">Call Us: +91 9711600069</span></a>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
      <section id="fixed-form-container">
       <div class="button blink">
        <span>Free Enquiry</span>
       </div>
       <div class="body">
        <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="Name">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact">Phone No.:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="Phoneno" class="form-control" id="contact">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: -38px;">
             <label for="email">Email address:</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Category Interested In</label>
          <select name="category" title="Center" class="form-control" required>
           <option value="">&nbsp;Category Interested In</option>
           <option value="Modular Furnitur">Modular Furniture</option>
           <option value="Home Furnishing">Home Furnishing</option>
           <option value="Kitchen Appliances">Kitchen Appliances</option>
          </select>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
         <div class="callus callus-phone">
          <a href="tel: +91 9711600069"><span class="call-phone-span call-span">Call Us: +91 9711600069</span></a>
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
       
      </section>
     </div>
```

I am trying to link two forms that are created using HTML with one `google sheet`. If i try adding two `SrciptURLs`, it shows an error. I want that data of both the forms can be seen in one `Google Sheet`. Is that possible? If yes, then how?
These are the forms along with the script that i added to link it to the Google Sheet.
There is no error when i fill in the entries and submit in both the forms but details of only one form can be seen in the Google Sheets.

Comment: Please update qour question and add relevant part of your code, more detaiés about the error message you got, etc.

Comment: Please format your code. The excessive indentation is making it hard to read.